# c++ Object creating new instances of same type

Tags: c++, object, types, instantiation

Is there a way to give an object the possibility to create new objects of it's own type, without specifying this type?

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual Foo* new_instance() {
        return new type_of(this); // Some magic here
    }
};

class Bar: public Foo {

};

Foo* a = new Foo();
Foo* b = new Bar();
Foo* c = a->new_instance();
Foo* d = b->new_instance();
```

I would now like `c` to be of type `Foo`, while `d` should be of type `Bar`.

Comment: Are you trying to define a singleton/factory?

Comment: Not a singleton. I'm not sure if it can be solved using a factory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is no way to make this magic happen.

You could use a macro to make overriding the function in subclasses easier, or create an intermediate class that uses the "curiously recurring template pattern":

```
template <typename T>
class FooDerived : public Foo
{
public:
    T* new_instance() {
        return new T();
    }
};

class Bar : public FooDerived<Bar>
{
};

Foo* a = new Bar();
Foo* b = a->new_instance(); // b is of type Bar*
```

But this is most certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: But when I want to add a new child class of Bar later on, I will have to make Bar a template class too. This will then break clients.

Comment: No, you don't have to make Bar a template for the same reason Foo is not a template.  If you really want to do that (but why would you?!!), you could make `FooDerived` take two parameters: `template <typename Derived, typename Base = Foo> class FooDerived : public Base`. Then you could do `class Buzz : public FooDerived<Buzz, Bar>`.

Comment: Okay, same argument: what happens when I want to introduce a new class Buzz derived from Bar?

Comment: First: My answer basically says "DON'T DO THIS".  I *do not* recommend using the template solution proposed here just to save a bit of typing.  Second: You did not understand my comment above!  When you change `FooDerived` to accept a `Base` parameter, you can use *any* `Foo`-derived class as a base, including `Buzz`.  If you want to create a class `Barbara` that extends `Buzz`, you can do: `class Barbara : public FooDerived<Barbara, Buzz>`.  You only need one template _per hierarchy_, not one per class.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual Foo* new_instance() {
        return new Foo();
    }
};

class Bar: public Foo {
public:
    virtual Foo* new_instance() {
        return new Bar();
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether there is a (non-straightforward) solution that lets me do this **without specifying the type**, hence without overloading in every derived class

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Mixin to add a factory class. It seems rather complicated for a factory function and is certainly harder to comprehend.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> class WithFactory: public T {
public:
    WithFactory<T>* new_instance() override {
        return new WithFactory<T>( );
    }
};

class FactoryFunction {
    virtual FactoryFunction* new_instance() = 0;
};

class Foo_: public FactoryFunction {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef WithFactory<Foo_> Foo;

class Bar_: public Foo {
public:
    virtual void f() override {
        std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef WithFactory<Bar_> Bar;

int main()
{
    Foo* a = new Foo();
    Foo* b = new Bar();
    Foo* c = a->new_instance();
    Foo* d = b->new_instance();

    assert( typeid(a) == typeid(c) );
    assert( typeid(b) == typeid(d) );

    a->f();
    b->f();
    c->f();
    d->f();

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have it do

```
virtual Foo* new_instance() { return new Foo(); }
```

And then in each derived class you overload it again to do the same (Although I much prefer the template approach to this sort of thing)

Comment: create new objects of it's own type, **without specifying this type**?

Comment: I don't believe so in C++, you can sort of pull something like this off (As in you won't have to type it out) if you use a template system to generate that code for you, but otherwise no.